# How to see last actions executed (and time) of a specific database in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

There are multiple databases but some of them look stale. I need to understand if the database is stale or not.

How can I get the last actions executed of a specific database in MongoDB? And can I get the date and time information of the last actions?

Comment: ,What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: 2.4 but we have different VMs with other Mongos such as 3.2, 3.4 and 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a quick way to check if a database is actively being used, you can use the [`top` administrative command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/top/). This command provides usage statistics with collection-level granularity.

For example, using the `mongo` shell to check if a `twitter.tweets` collection is being actively queried:

```
>  db.adminCommand('top').totals["twitter.tweets"].queries
{ "time" : 1414008, "count" : 23779 }
```

The `time` value is in microseconds and the `count` indicates how many operations were observed since this `mongod` last restarted. For an unused collection both of these values would be low or 0.

You can sample `top` metrics over time to see if counters continue to increment due to usage.

If you want to check which commands are being run against a database, enable the [Database Profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) with profiling level 2 (all operations):

```
> use mydb
switched to db mydb

> db.setProfilingLevel(2)
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "sampleRate" : 1, "ok" : 1 }
```

This will enabling logging of all recent queries and commands for the current database in a `system.profile` [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/). You can then count or find recent operations by querying the `system.profile` collection.

There are a number of fields in the [`system.profile` documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#example-system-profile-document) that may be helpful to match on, such as: `op` (type of operation), `ts` (timestamp), and `client` (IP address or hostname where an operation originated. At a minimum you'll probably want to match on the `ns` (namespace) value, because profiling level 2 will also include queries against the `system.profile` collection.

A capped collection has the helpful property of guaranteeing insertion order, so a sort by `$natural` order can be used to find oldest or newest profile documents.

A few examples:

```
// Count the number of recent operations for twitter.tweets
> db.system.profile.find({ns:'twitter.tweets'}).count()

// Find the latest query profiled for twitter.tweets
> db.system.profile.find(
     {ns:'twitter.tweets','op':'query'}
  ).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getLog/) through [getLog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getLog/) is an administrative command that returns the most recent **1024** logged mongod events.

The `getLog` does not read log data from the `mongod` log file. It instead reads data from a **RAM** cache of logged `mongod` events. To run `getLog`, use the `db.runCommand( { command } )` method on the **admin** database.

The getLog command has the following syntax:

```
{ getLog: <value> }
```

The possible values for **`getLog`** are:

- global - returns the combined output of all recent log entries.
- rs - if the mongod is part of a replica set, getLog returns recent
  notices related to replica set activity.
- startupWarnings - returns logs that may contain errors or warnings
  from MongoDB’s log from when the current process started. If mongod
  started without warnings, this filter may return an empty array.

***Retrieve Recent Events from Log***

The following operation retrieves the most recent global events for the mongod

```
db.adminCommand( { getLog : "global" } )
```

For your further ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/)

Comment: Thank you but it does not give information per database. It gives the log of all dbs. Not a specific db. If there is a parameter for db, I would appreciate the way how to get that.